# Distribute python for loops on cluster/grid

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cluster-computing, gpu, grid-computing

Say I have a `python` script that looks like below. Since `python` is `single threaded`, what tool would I use to distribute the `loops` on different `cores/computers`?

```
series=pandas.Series()

# evaluate an model 
def evaluate_model(X, O):
    ...

def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                try:
                    mse = evaluate_model(dataset, order)
                    if mse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = mse, order
                    print('A%s MSE=%.3f' % (order, mse))
                except:
                    continue
    print('Best model%s MSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))


# evaluate parameters
p_values = [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
d_values = range(0, 3)
q_values = range(0, 3)

evaluate_models(series.values, p_values, d_values, q_values)
```

It would be nice if I could say:

```
run_on_grid(evaluate_models(series.values, p_values, d_values, q_values))
```

It would be nicer if "run_on_grid" could be configured to point to a local `GPU`.

Comment: You mean like ``multiprocess.Pool.map``? What's the point of running on a grid if all you care about is a local GPU?

Comment: I just care about how fast the result comes back. Why would I care about the details of how that is done? In an ideal world, the backend is totally unknown to the consumer of "cores"

Comment: You should care because you have to. Most cluster middlewares are not interchangeable, especially for newer technologies such as accelerators. Even what "cluster" or "grid" even means depends entirely on the domain. Finally, "distributed" computation and "local" resource are entirely different things.

Comment: Having to care is different than what your original comment implied. My understanding is that you implied that I would care about running on a cluster vs a local GPU - not because  I have to mind the fact that middle-ware are not interchangeable.

Comment: multiprocess.Pool.map looks interesting...

Comment: You said you want ``run_on_grid`` to be able to point to "a local GPU" - which is not at all what running on a grid usually means, matching that you see it as "distribute on ... different cores/computers".

Comment: Ah I see the confusion. Yeah, I meant, "run_on_grid" in quotes, where "grid" could be a set of cores on a local GPU or a set of cores out on the network. I might be abusing "grid" in this case.